# How to add point features with coords taken from a .txt and show them on the map canvas?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point

Ok, so i am on Windows 7 and using QGIS 2.6 and i have a .txt file with some simple coords. I have extracted the coords to a list, no prob with that. But i looked at the PyQGIS cookbook on how to add features and the code is somewhat obsolete for example .addAttribute(0, 'hello') has changed to setAttribute. Anyway, i already have an empty point vector layer ready and 3 fields on it: id,x,y. I also need to fill them up as well, as i add the points to the map.[image]

My code so far is:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()
points=[]
txt=open('C:/users/stelios/desktop/vasia/points.txt','r')

for line in txt.readlines():
    points.append(line.split())
    
print points
#so far so good, now i need to fix the part where i actually add the points and show them in the map

for x,y in points:
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setAttribute(0, "1")
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(float(x), float(y))))
    (res, outFeats) = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
    

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
txt.close()
```

When i try this i get a:
feat.setAttribute(0, "1")
KeyError: '0'

isnt the first value of setAttrubute, the index of the field i want to edit? So 0='id',1='x' and 2='y' or am i missing something? IF i remove the setAttribute line, then it works just fine and i see my points where they should be after i zoom to layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest setAttributes() which takes the list of attribute values, for example

```
feat.setAttributes([id,x,y])
```

You can find more examples in the Vector section of the [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html). It's true that the C++ Api doc can be difficult to interpret that's why the PyQGIS Cookbook is important and any [outdated code snippets should be reported on the issue tracker](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues).

Comment: YES ma'am! But how did you know you had to add the [] inside the parenthesis? I mean i went to the QGIS API documentation to check out the .setAttributes and given that i cant read C++ i got confused. I really should learn how to interpret the documentation so i spam less on this site!